# Inconsistency in real analysis notes: $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

There are two perspectives that I have seen presented simultaneously in analysis courses, but which seem to be at odds with each other.

Perspective 1) The real numbers are a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ because $x = x + 0i$.

Perspective 2) The real numbers are embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ by the mapping $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}, \; x \mapsto x + 0i$.

In this second case, it is not true that $x = x + 0i$, but rather that $f(x) = x + 0i$. Then, it is not that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, but rather than the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under the map $f$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which obeys precisely the same properties as $\mathbb{R}$ because the field operations in $\mathbb{R}$ are consistent with those in $\mathbb{C}$.

Are these perspectives in fact mutually exclusive? Is this simply an abuse of notation? Is one more typical than the other?

Comment: It's partially an abuse of notation. It's not technically true since the complex numbers are typically built up from $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is fundamentally different from $\mathbb{R}$) and thus $\mathbb{R}$ cannot satisfy the construction of the complex numbers. When there is an obvious, canonical way to embed one object into another, we typically just say object A is a subobject of object B. I'm sure some category theorists (or category theory aficionados) will have some nice language this can be cast in, but this is the general idea.

Comment: It really depends how you define each set. It would be similar for $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$. Using typical definitions, it would be a very common abuse of notation, but which is harmless for all intents and purposes.

Comment: I had the same thought, Raoul. If integers are defined, for example, as differences of natural numbers, $n \mapsto n - 0$ is an embedding of $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{N} \not \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Dropping the $n - 0$  notation for $\mathbb{Z}$ seems to be what allows us to assert $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every construction of the complex field that I am aware of, $\Bbb R\not\subset\Bbb C$. But in each case we identify the real field with a subfield of the complex field. After that, yes, by an abuse of notation, we say that $\Bbb R$ is a subset of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: You could say that $\mathbb{C}$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{R}$ and $i$ where $i^2 = -1$. Would that not be a common construction that has $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$

Comment: But in order to prove that such a field exists, you must construct it somehow. Are you aware of any constrution of $\Bbb C$ such that $\Bbb C\supset\Bbb R$?

Comment: I cannot think of a construction in the sense of a description of it's elements but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but I guess that's not what you are saying? I think I have just confused myself to be honest.

Comment: If you want a real inclusion, you could first go up: construct $\mathbb{N}' \subset \mathbb{Z}' \subset \mathbb{Q}' \subset \mathbb{R}' \subset \mathbb{C}'$ in usual ways; then go down, and define $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C'}$, $\mathbb{R} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, \; \Im(z) = 0 \}$, and so on.